# Is there any way to reduce the size of a portion of text present as a header in a Markdown file?

Tags: github, version-control, markdown, text-formatting, readme

So I was formatting the text of a Readme.md file on GitHub. I wanted one portion of the heading [styled as heading1], to reduce in size and come right below that heading in order to just beautify the overall appearance.

**Here is how the text looks right now:**
[image]

I want this portion 'yet another ---------------- model', to be displayed right below the Main heading and with a size which is smaller as compared to that main heading 'A TensorFlow Implementation of XYZ'.

**This is how I want it to be:**
[image]

I searched about the same but couldn't find anything supporting my question. Also, I just started using GitHub and I'm exploring around starting with Text formatting in the markdown files. And, yes it is my first question here on stack overflow.

Really looking forward to hearing an answer. Any little help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Stop worrying so much about what _you_ think is "beautiful". That's in the eye of the beholder and lots of folks would disagree that the second option is better in any way. The whole point of Markdown is to let you focus on _content_, not presentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a styling issue which would be done with CSS.  GitHub does not permit CSS to be used in READMEs or other documents it renders on the site for security, accessibility, and design reasons, so this is not something you can do.

You'll need to just write your Markdown (or other markup language, like AsciiDoc) in a standard, semantically meaningful way, and let it be rendered, on GitHub or otherwise, as the given tool renders it.